# How to build a service on ifttt?

Tags: triggers, action, alexa-skills-kit, ifttt, alexa-smart-home-skill

I'm a newbie when it comes to IFTTT, I want to create a service on ifttt but I'm a little bit confused. I found that I need to have an IFTTT service URL(api), but I still don't know what kind of url! is ifttt has an sdk like alexa and google actions? or how ifttt can understand my api response?

Answer (score 0):

Yes IFTTT provides connect SDK for andoid and IOS which used integrate the API into your mobile apps. Before handling the connect sdk code you need to create a service(path to create a service is= https://ifttt.com/docs -> add service).Fill all the required service details. u need to have a server to expose your service and its endpoints over internet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Specific steps (included in the answer, not just linked to) & specific links (i.e.   https://ifttt.com/docs/example_services   not just a general link to the docs; are more helpful.